# How to use purescript-css to set CSS margin property to auto?

Tags: css, purescript, purescript-pux

I am converting a CSS file to `purescript-css` and in the CSS file there is the line `margin:auto` . I have looked at the `margin` function in the `CSS.Geometry` module of the purescript-css library and I cannot see how to use it to set the `margin` property to `auto`. Can anyone help?

Sincerely,
Eric M.

Comment: There is an `auto` function here https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-css/4.0.0/docs/CSS.Common#t:Auto, so maybe you can write `margin auto auto auto auto`.